# CSV files and dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create CSV file, based on iterating over other CSV files. The output CSV file, is in a slightly different format to the input ones.

My question is, being quite new to Python, how I'd go about doing this?

My input is something like this:

```
1.csv
"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "7", "4"
"Test Street", "5", "1"
"Test Avenue, "2", "6"

2.csv
"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "12", "2"
"Test Street", "11", "3"
"Test Avenue, "9", "2"

3.csv
"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "34", "2"
"Test Street", "22", "3"
"Test Lane", "19", "2"

expected_output.csv
"", "Street", "1", "2", "3"
"Number", "Test Road", "7", "12", "34"
"", "Test Street", "5", "11", "22"
"", "Test Avenue", "2", "9", "N/A"
"", "Test Lane", "N/A", "N/A", "19"
"Occupants", "Test Road", "4", "2", "2"
"", "Test Street", "1", "3", "3"
"", "Test Avenue", "6", "2", "N/A"
"", "Test Lane", "N/A", "N/A", "2"
```

So you can see across the top of the output i have `Number/Occupants`, `Street` and then the number of the input cvs file (1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv etc)

If a particular street is not in the input file, then the output should display `N/A` for the `Number` or `Occupant`

I'm not sure what the best/fastest approach to this is. Either concatenating all the CSV files together first, maybe in a dictionary, then doing some complex loop or have several loops to create the output.

Comment: Using a dictionary is a good idea ;) Maybe you should try that out yourself and come back to us if you have difficulties implementing it.

Comment: Also, you'll want to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to implement reading and writing the various CSV files.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go. I'm still really new to Python, so I'm a little confused about syntax/best practices.

Comment: Work in progress, I'll have something that's reasonably self explanatory in a few minutes.

Comment: @AustinKootz that would be awesome! I've been struggling to get something working

Comment: How locked into the output format are you? Pulling and sorting the data has turned out to be very easy. Getting the format to be flexible relative to the input is easy. Getting the output to be 'smart' isn't.

Comment: As long as the output is similar to the above I'm ok with that. All I need is the differentiation between `Numbers` and `Occupants` and the number of the name/number of the CSV as a column with the values

Comment: @AustinKootz also, what do you mean by 'smart'?

Comment: The data processing can account for various file sizes (additional rows oor columns) without a need for the user to modify the python script.

Comment: @AustinKootz It is likely there will be more than the 3 input files (this was just a small example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91460/discussion-between-sipher-z-and-austin-kootz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in chat, here's a full program including some test files. You will only need to delete the labeled lines to use your own files.

```
#user configurable variables:
number_of_files = 4

#delete the following lines to use your own files.
f1 = open('1.csv','w')
f1.write('''"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "7", "4"
"Test Street", "5", "1"
"Test Avenue", "2", "6"''')
f1.close()

f2 = open('2.csv','w')
f2.write('''"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "12", "2"
"Test Street", "11", "3"
"Test Avenue", "9", "2"''')
f2.close()

f3 = open('3.csv','w')
f3.write('''"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "34", "2"
"Test Street", "22", "3"
"Test Lane", "19", "2"''')
f3.close()

f4 = open('4.csv','w')
f4.write('''"Street", "Number", "Occupants"
"Test Road", "4", "7"
"Test Street", "1243", "6"
"Test Lane", "17", "1"''')
f4.close()
#stop deleteing

#the rest 'should' take care of itself.
file_set = []
for y in range(number_of_files):
    exec("f"+str(y+1)+" = [x.split(',') for x in open('"+str(y+1)+".csv','r').read().replace('\"','').replace(', ',',').split('\\n')]")
    exec("file_set.append(f"+str(y+1)+")")

num_files = len(file_set)

data_dict = {}

for file in file_set:
    block = file_set.index(file)

    for line in file:
        row = file.index(line)

        if line[0] not in data_dict:
            data_dict[line[0]] = num_files*[['N/A','N/A']]

        data_dict[line[0]][block] = line[1:]

print (data_dict)


f0 = open('output.csv','w')
f0.write(',Street')
for x in range(num_files):
    f0.write(','+str(x+1))
f0.write('\n')

temp = 0
for key in data_dict:
    if key != 'Street':
        if temp == 0:
            f0.write('Number,'+key)
            temp = 1
        else:
            f0.write(','+key)
        for x in range(num_files):
            f0.write(','+data_dict[key][x][0])
        f0.write('\n')

temp = 0
for key in data_dict:
    if key != 'Street':
        if temp == 0:
            f0.write('Occupants,'+key)
            temp = 1
        else:
            f0.write(','+key)
        for x in range(num_files):
            f0.write(','+data_dict[key][x][1])
        f0.write('\n')

f0.close()
```

Enjoy, and have a great day.